# Creating a file with the same name as registry

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a text file with the same name as a registry.

Say, I get the variable valueName, and I want it's value to be the name of a .txt file in C:\ How can I do that?

Almost final code:

```
void EnumerateValues(HKEY hKey, DWORD numValues)
{
    for (DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < numValues; dwIndex++)
    {BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;
    char valueName[64];
    DWORD valNameLen = sizeof(valueName);
    DWORD dataType;
    DWORD dataSize = 0;
    DWORD retval = RegEnumValue(hKey, dwIndex, valueName, &valNameLen,
        NULL, &dataType, NULL, &dataSize);

    if (retval == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {//pregatesc calea
        char* val = new char[strlen(valueName)];
        sprintf(val, "C:\\%s.txt", valueName);
        printf("S-a creat fisierul: %s\n", val);

        //creez/suprascriu fisierul
        HANDLE hFile;
        hFile=CreateFile(val,GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        { printf("Eroare la creat fisierul %s!\n",val);
            }

        //sciru in fisier
        char str[] = "Example text testing WriteFile";
        DWORD bytesWritten=0;
        DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(str);

        bErrorFlag=WriteFile(hFile, str, dwBytesToWrite, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
            {
            printf("Eroare la scriere in fisier\n");
            }
        //inchid fisierul
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        }
    //eroare regenumv
    else printf("\nError RegEnumValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: concatenate `"C:\\"` with `valueName` using one of the many methods.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: looks like a lot of C code. If you want to do it the C way, `sprintf` is an option, for C++ you could use a `strstream` or just `std::string`.

Comment: `"C:\\" + valueName` if `valueName` is a `std::string`. A `stringstream`, `strcat`, `sprintf`, array manipulation...

Comment: I tried sprintf but it still gives me problems. I'm not exactly sure how should I do it. How do I get my path from the handle?

Comment: hKey is not a string. You've neglected error checking. Your code leaks. It's basically pointless trying to help you unless you start checking for errors. Otherwise we'll just have to write your entire program for you.

Comment: This time I got no errors, but it doesn't create the required files. Mind checking again, please?

Comment: did you try the stringstream answer?

Comment: No, but this should work, too. It doesn't, though.

Comment: `char* val = new char[strlen(valueName)];` <- `val` is not long enough. If you are doing C++ code, you should really be using C++ `std::string`, otherwise be more careful about your memory allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you seem to want to convert a registry key, `HKEY` into a path. And there's no API to do that. You will need to keep track of the path and pass it to the function in the question, along with the `HKEY`.

You are passing uninitialized values to `RegEnumValue`, specifically `dataSize`. Since you don't care about the data, don't ask for it. Pass `NULL` for the data pointer, and zero for data size.

Your call to `new` is not allocating enough memory. You need space for the directory name, the file extension, and the null-terminator.

These problems are exacerbated by your complete neglect for error checking. That might sound harsh, but frankly you need some shock treatment. In order to be able to fail gracefully you need to check for errors. More pressing for you, in order to be able to debug code, you need to check for errors.

You've tagged the code C++ but write as if it were C. If you really are using C++ then you can use standard containers, `std::string`, avoid raw memory allocation and the result leaks. Yes, you code leaks as it stands.

Comment: I changed the code, I don't pass hkey, I pass valueName to the function now. It's just that it doesn't create the files that I need.

Comment: Am I to keep updating my answer with every trial and error change you make. Step 1, add error checking.

Comment: I get no error, just that the valueName gets strange characters as value instead of the actual name of the registry.

Comment: You do get loads of errors. You just ignore them. You do not check the return value of any of the API functions that you call. I know Win32 very well. You will make no progress until you learn how to check for errors. It is particularly galling because I've already been through this once with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133265/print-name-type-and-data-of-registry. Please add error checking.

Comment: Ohhh, I know, but it still works. I just get funny characters. I will treat the errors after I make it work.

Comment: @user That's ass backwards. Check for errors and that will tell you where to fix your code. In other words, the quickest way to make the code work is to add error checking!

Comment: The reason the filename is garbage is that the call to RegEnumValue fails. The erroneous new and subsequent buffer overrun do not help. In the question I linked to I already told you that you have to initialize certain params that are passed to RegEnumValue. You must heed that advice. Error checking will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: So, deal with paragraphs 2 and 3 from my answer, and you will have success. But I urge you to learn about error checking. Otherwise you'll spend the rest of your life asking this same question.

Comment: Ok, done error check and you are right, it does fail. What's the next step?

Comment: Exactly as I say in paras 2 and 3. And consult my answer to the other question that I linked above.

Comment: I initialised valnamelen and datasize and I check for error. Oh wait, paragraph from your answer. I thought your 2nd and 3rd comments. Wait a sec.

Comment: Ok, fixed errors regarding creating the file, but now I got errors writing to the file. What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: Also, your params to CreateFile are wrong. No need for read access. And don't share it.

Comment: It works with no errors at the moment. Just needs a few more tweaks.

Comment: Not really. You still need to address paragraph 3 in my answer. And you still leak.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Should I just give it more than 64 or is there a better way? And what is leak?

Comment: No, the static 64 char arrays are fine. It's the call to new that is no good. Read para 3 again you'll see what I mean. Long term, using std::string makes this loads easier.

Answer (score 1):

first of all your program is more C like than C++, but if you want to solve this in C++ you can use stringstream in the following way:

```
std::stringstream stream;

stream << "C:\\";
stream << valueName;
stream << ".txt";
std::string filename(stream.str());

    HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(filename.c_str() ,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,
                            NULL, CREATE_NEW , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

Also you need a include:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: You need to assign str() to a local, and then call c_str() on that string variable.

Comment: it's true, I am more familiar with fstreams than this way to manage files, is edited now.